# CommandLine using ProcessBuilder in Java and pipe between programs

Tags: java, command-line, processbuilder

I've looking to run the following Unix command from Javas' ProcessBuilder (in Windows).

```
$ gensky 1 21 11 | genskyvec -m 1 > skyvec_1-21-11_1.skv
```

So I've written this:

```
String cmd = String.format("C:\\Radiance4.2\\bin\\gensky 1 21 11 | %s -m 1 > %s\n", "C:\\Radiance4.2\\bin\\genskyvec", "C:\\Radiance4.2\\temp\\output_test.skv");
```

And this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);                  
Process process = null;
try {
    process = builder.start();
    System.out.println("Started Processing!");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But continue to get error - that program not found. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `List<String>` to pass parameters

Comment: ie. List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
     command.add("cmd.exe");
     command.add("/C");
     command.add("start");

Comment: I suppose it is `gensky.exe` etc. on windows. And i suppose `gensky.exe` knows nothing about piping, this is a feature of the shell (if one wants to call `cmd.exe` a shell..).

Answer (score 0):

use [`directory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) to set working directory to `C:\\Radiance4.2\\bin\\` and pass `List<String>`

List cmd = new ArrayList();
cmd.add("genskyvec");
cmd.add("1");
cmd.add("21");
cmd.add("11");
// all parameters

and use [`redirectOutput()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput%28java.io.File%29) to file you are passing with `>`

Comment: This worked thanks. However, the second program "genskyvec" which the output of "gensky" is piped to, is written as a Perl batch job. Any idea how I can execute a windows cmd.exe to just run the entire unix command at once? I don't need to capture the process output in Java as the programs already output data files in specific folders.

Comment: can you redirect output from first command in a temporary file and then read that file and feed the data as input to second command ?

Comment: Yes, that I tried this. But the Perl script is completely alien to me. I tried to find a read() function inside the Perl but don't understand it.

Comment: try changing command to not include full path to binary and keep setting working dir `directory()` as mentioned and include `|` in command list

Comment: It seems to have been written specifically with piping the first program output into the Perl batch - http://radsite.lbl.gov/radiance/man_html/genskyvec.1.html

Comment: yes keep pipe just set directory so that it can find program

Comment: Tried the above. The output file is an error for the first program. The error says the input parameters are not correct.

Comment: you need to play around with what is exactly being passed in and fix it